# Spertulo pri StackExchange por podkasta diskuto

Tags: support

Por la Esperanta podkasto kern.punkto ni ŝatus eldoni epizodon pri StackExchange. Por tio ni serĉas spertan StackExchange-anon, kiu jam delonge estas aktiva en StackExchange kaj ankaŭ povas rakonti pri la historio de ĝi. Speciale demandoj kial oni fondis ĝin, kiujn problemojn de kutimaj forumoj ĝi celas solvi, kiel ĝi funkcias, kio estas la gravaj okazoj en la historio de SE ĝis nun, ktp.

La interparolo daŭros inter 45 kaj 90 minutoj. Nia studio troviĝas proksime de Stuttgart, Germanio. Ankaŭ eblus por ni vojaĝi kelkcent kilometrojn semajnfine. Plia eblo estas distanca parolado

Ĉu iu interesiĝas?

Comment: Hmm, mi estis aktiva dum pluraj jaroj (de 2011) en Stack Overflow kaj Crypto SE (kie mi estis ankaŭ moderatoro). Sed mi nek ĉeestis la fondon nek estas aktiva lastatempe, do ne certas ĉu mi estus la plej bona fonto.